# dollar sign in environment variable specified when launching docker container

Tags: docker, redmine

I'm running redmine in a docker container. Within redmine I want to send email through smtp. To do that I need to set environment variables when launching the container, eg.:

`docker run --name=redmine ... --env='SMTP_HOST=host.com' --env='SMTP_USER=user@host.com' --env='SMTP_PASS=$mypassword'`

I didn't choose the password, and unfortunately it really starts with a dollar sign. If I just provide the password as is in the container the variable SMTP_PASS is empty, as there is no variable 'mypassword' defined. How to specify the password containing the $-sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape it with a backslash: `--env='SMTP_PASS=\$mypassword'`

Comment: Thanks, that works! The docker container creates a config/configuration.yml file containing the password between quotes. As a result, sending email through smtp works.